# How to improve the computation speed of subsetting a pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a large df (14*1'000'000) and I want to subset it. The calculation seems to take unsurprisingly a lot of time though and I wonder how to improve the speed.

What I want is to subset for each `Name` the lowest value of `Total_time` while ignoring zero values and picking only the first one if there is more than one row has the lowest value of `Total_time`. And then I want it to be all appended into a new dataframe `unique`.

Is there a general mistake in my code that makes it inefficient?

```
unique = pd.DataFrame([])
i=0
for pair in df['Name'].unique():
    i=i+1
    temp =df[df["Name"]== pair]
    temp2 = temp.loc[df['Total_time']  != 0]
    lowest = temp2['Total_time'].min()
    temp3 = temp2[temp2["Total_time"] == lowest].head(1)
    unique = unique.append(temp3)
    print("finished "+ pair + " "+ str(i))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

in general, you don't want to iterate over  each item.

if you want the Name with the smallest time:

```
new_df = df[df["Total_time"] != 0].copy() # you seem to be throwing away 0
out = new_df.groupby("Name")["Total_time"].min()
```

If you need the rest of the columns:

```
new_df.loc[new_df.groupby("Name")["total_time"].idxmin()]
```

Comment: This is definitely way faster. I do lose many other columns though that are relevant in later steps. How can this be avoided with your code?

Comment: new_.loc[new_df.groupby("Name")["total_time"].idxmin()]

Answer (score 1):

> What I want is to subset for each `Name` the lowest value of
> `Total_time` while ignoring zero values and picking only the first one
> if there is more than one row has the lowest value of `Total_time`.

This sounds like task for [`pandas.Series.idxmin`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.idxmin.html) consider following simple example

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({"X":["A","B","C","D","E"],"Y":[5.5,0.0,5.5,1.5,1.5]})
first_min = df.Y.replace(0,float("nan")).idxmin()
print(df.iloc[first_min])
```

output

```
X      D
Y    1.5
Name: 3, dtype: object
```

Explanation: replace 0 with NaN so they are not considered, then use idxmin to get index of 1st minimum, which might be used with `.iloc`.

Comment: Thank you, this seems to ignore the "group by Name" though, am I right?

Comment: @Yves, yes it does